# Countability in practice

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am studying the function portion of discrete mathematics and I am wondering to know that how can we practically count the integers?
As they are saying these are countable.

Comment: $1\mapsto0,2\mapsto1,3\mapsto-1,4\mapsto2,5\mapsto-2,\ldots$

Comment: Countable means they can be out in correspondence with the natural numbers.   consider $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,...$

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your point correctly.

Comment: Like there is a question that prove that 3.Z is countable. Where Z is integers. How can I prove this?

Comment: @KaranSingh The definition of being countable is to have the same cardinality (or less) than the natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \dots\}$ (although some people make the distinction that to be countable, the set must be infinite). Thus if you can show an injection of a set $S$ into $\mathbb{N}$, you have shown that the set is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "countable" in math just means that we can assign each "object", "label", or "symbol" an integer number without repeats.

The set of integers is infinite, yet we can give each integer it's own number. We can label 1 as "1", 2 as "2", 3 as "3" and so on... (Of course we can do this for negative numbers too).

This might be confusing to grasp, but their are higher order infinities, meaning that some infinities are larger than others. That is, there are *countable* infinities and there are *uncountable* infinities. The set of real numbers is uncountable. You can use up all the numbers in the set of integers and still not be able to label all the real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The term *countable* refers to a set $X$ the elements of which can be listed  (*though infinite possibly*) such that you can always find an index in your list corresponding to any arbitrary element of $X$.

If you are unable to list the elements of $X$ without skipping the an infinite subset $Y\subset X$ then $X$ is uncountable. A good example is the set of reals $\mathbb R$ where you cannot list its elements without skipping a subset $\mathbb Q^c$ (set of irrational numbers).